# What cable to connect Inspiron 1720 to HDMI TV?

Tags: hdmi, vga

I'm a little confused to say the least when it comes to video formats and protocols. I'd like to view my laptop output on my HD TV.

The TV has HDMI, S-Video, and RCA inputs.

My laptop has a VGA female port on the side for driving a 2nd monitor, and an S-VHS output at the back. No, it has no DVI, which I've heard is a poor decision from DELL, and even poorer decision on my part to buy it.

- Can I get true HD output from this to my TV?
- What cable do I need, or would I need a converter?

Any other suggestions are also welcome, such as how to get something close to HD on my TV.

Thanks!
Bernhard

Comment: Did you mean S-Video instead of S-VHS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, this will do:

VGA to HDMI cable or adapter

[image]

If you also want to feed the audio signal to HDMI, you can use a converter like this:

[image]

However you will only get an analog signal which is of inferior quality.

Comment: What's that called, and where can I buy it?

Comment: edited answer, where can you buy? check this link: http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.13189

Comment: This is NOT what you want. VGA is analog and HDMI is digital. You can use that convertor box, but that cable will not do as you expect. Read the link that Molly added, the description even states:
"this cable will not convert regular VGA video card signal to HDMI. It is not a PC-to-TV cable. This cable will only work on specific devices that output digital HDMI signals via VGA ports"